# ESIDIR Error in NextJs, even if the code come from the official page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to learn Next.js for an interview, so I started to follow the tutorial published in [Next.js official web page](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app).

It was all ok, until I arrived [at this section](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/implement-getstaticprops) about the implementation of getStaticProps.

I wrote this code as the tutorial says:

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import matter from 'gray-matter'

const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'posts')

export function getSortedPostsData() {
  // Get file names under /posts
  const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory)
  const allPostsData = fileNames.map(fileName => {
    // Remove ".md" from file name to get id
    const id = fileName.replace(/\.md$/, '')

    // Read markdown file as string
    const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, fileName)
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8')

    // Use gray-matter to parse the post metadata section
    const matterResult = matter(fileContents)

    // Combine the data with the id
    return {
      id,
      ...matterResult.data
    }
  })
  // Sort posts by date
  return allPostsData.sort(({ date: a }, { date: b }) => {
    if (a < b) {
      return 1
    } else if (a > b) {
      return -1
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  })
}
```

So I changed index.js to look like this:

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import Layout, { siteTitle } from '../components/layout'
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css'

import { getSortedPostsData } from '../lib/post'

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const allPostsData = getSortedPostsData()
  return {
    props: {
      allPostsData
    }
  }
}

export default function Home({ allPostsData }) {
  return (
    <Layout home>
    <Head>
      <title>{siteTitle}</title>
    </Head>
    <section className={utilStyles.headingMd}>
      <p>[Your Self Introduction]</p>
      <p>
        (This is a sample website - you’ll be building a site like this on{' '}
        <a href="https://nextjs.org/learn">our Next.js tutorial</a>.)
      </p>
    </section>

    <section className={`${utilStyles.headingMd} ${utilStyles.padding1px}`}>
        <h2 className={utilStyles.headingLg}>Blog</h2>
        <ul className={utilStyles.list}>
          {allPostsData.map(({ id, date, title }) => (
            <li className={utilStyles.listItem} key={id}>
              {title}
              <br />
              {id}
              <br />
              {date}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
  </Layout>

  )
}
```

However, when I run the code onscreen I see this error:
[image]

I know that ESIDIR means "Error, Is Directory" but I can't find a way to fix it and I don't understand why I have this error.

Comment: You probably have a subdirectory in your posts/ directory, and you're not filtering them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EISDIR in your case means you're trying to read a directory as a file.

To fix it use [fs.statSync](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fsfstatsyncfd-options) method to check wether the path is file or not. It might look like this:

```js
fs.statSync(path.join(postsDirectory, fileName)).isFile()
```

**UPD**. Also I'd suggest to check wether file has `.md` extension or not. Currently you just replace it when it's presented. So even if the file has different extension it would be processed by your code. Use check like this:

```fs
path.extname(fileName) === '.md'
```

Comment: I have put two .md files before write the post file, following the tutorial instructions (https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/blog-data). Now I am going to check.

Comment: Solved! I make an error with the directories of the .md files.

Comment: Glad it helps. So if it solves your issue then it's better to accept my answer. There is an explanation of how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers